# excel sumif multiple columns data

Tags: arrays, excel

My data is:

[image]

I need to calculate a sum of the "col1" and "col2" where "name" is "a": 1+2+5+6 = 14.

Now I am using:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"a",B:B)+SUMIF(A:A,"a",C:C)
```

Is there any better way (eg with arrays)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for the sum of values where name is a,

Formula in cell **B6** --> `Applicable To All Excel Users`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$4=$A6)*($B$2:$C$4))
```

Formula in cell **C6** --> `Applicable To Only O365 & Excel 2021 Users`

```
=SUM(FILTER($B$2:$C$4,A6=$A$2:$A$4))
```

[image: SUMPRODUCT]